# How to set different home page of website for mobile and pc?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am creating my website, it is working completely fine on desktop version but when I am trying to open it on android mobile the problems occurring are:

1. The menu does not appear to the user.(the black section below header section)
2. In categories section the drop-down list is not opening (I have used JQuery in this section).

here is my (demo) website url: [Link](http://www.smartbillionaires.com).

**JQuery**

```
/*
* EASYDROPDOWN - A Drop-down Builder for Styleable Inputs and Menus
* Version: 2.1.4
* License: Creative Commons Attribution 3.0 Unported - CC BY 3.0
* http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by/3.0/
* This software may be used freely on commercial and non-commercial projects with attribution to the author/copyright holder.
* Author: Patrick Kunka
* Copyright 2013 Patrick Kunka, All Rights Reserved
*/


(function($){

    function EasyDropDown(){
        this.isField = true,
        this.down = false,
        this.inFocus = false,
        this.disabled = false,
        this.cutOff = false,
        this.hasLabel = false,
        this.keyboardMode = false,
        this.nativeTouch = true,
        this.wrapperClass = 'dropdown',
        this.onChange = null;
    };

    EasyDropDown.prototype = {
        constructor: EasyDropDown,
        instances: {},
        init: function(domNode, settings){
            var self = this;

            $.extend(self, settings);
            self.$select = $(domNode);
            self.id = domNode.id;
            self.options = [];
            self.$options = self.$select.find('option');
            self.isTouch = 'ontouchend' in document;
            self.$select.removeClass(self.wrapperClass+' dropdown');
            if(self.$select.is(':disabled')){
                self.disabled = true;
            };
            if(self.$options.length){
                self.$options.each(function(i){
                    var $option = $(this);
                    if($option.is(':selected')){
                        self.selected = {
                            index: i,
                            title: $option.text()
                        }
                        self.focusIndex = i;
                    };
                    if($option.hasClass('label') && i == 0){
                        self.hasLabel = true;
                        self.label = $option.text();
                        $option.attr('value','');
                    } else {
                        self.options.push({
                            domNode: $option[0],
                            title: $option.text(),
                            value: $option.val(),
                            selected: $option.is(':selected')
                        });
                    };
                });
                if(!self.selected){
                    self.selected = {
                        index: 0,
                        title: self.$options.eq(0).text()
                    }
                    self.focusIndex = 0;
                };
                self.render();
            };
        },

        render: function(){
            var self = this,
                touchClass = self.isTouch && self.nativeTouch ? ' touch' : '',
                disabledClass = self.disabled ? ' disabled' : '';

            self.$container = self.$select.wrap('<div class="'+self.wrapperClass+touchClass+disabledClass+'"><span class="old"/></div>').parent().parent();
            self.$active = $('<span class="selected">'+self.selected.title+'</span>').appendTo(self.$container);
            self.$carat = $('<span class="carat"/>').appendTo(self.$container);
            self.$scrollWrapper = $('<div><ul/></div>').appendTo(self.$container);
            self.$dropDown = self.$scrollWrapper.find('ul');
            self.$form = self.$container.closest('form');
            $.each(self.options, function(){
                var option = this,
                    active = option.selected ? ' class="active"':'';
                self.$dropDown.append('<li'+active+'>'+option.title+'</li>');
            });
            self.$items = self.$dropDown.find('li');

            if(self.cutOff && self.$items.length > self.cutOff)self.$container.addClass('scrollable');

            self.getMaxHeight();

            if(self.isTouch && self.nativeTouch){
                self.bindTouchHandlers();
            } else {
                self.bindHandlers();
            };
        },

        getMaxHeight: function(){
            var self = this;

            self.maxHeight = 0;

            for(i = 0; i < self.$items.length; i++){
                var $item = self.$items.eq(i);
                self.maxHeight += $item.outerHeight();
                if(self.cutOff == i+1){
                    break;
                };
            };
        },

        bindTouchHandlers: function(){
            var self = this;
            self.$container.on('click.easyDropDown',function(){
                self.$select.focus();
            });
            self.$select.on({
                change: function(){
                    var $selected = $(this).find('option:selected'),
                        title = $selected.text(),
                        value = $selected.val();

                    self.$active.text(title);
                    if(typeof self.onChange === 'function'){
                        self.onChange.call(self.$select[0],{
                            title: title, 
                            value: value
                        });
                    };
                },
                focus: function(){
                    self.$container.addClass('focus');
                },
                blur: function(){
                    self.$container.removeClass('focus');
                }
            });
        },

        bindHandlers: function(){
            var self = this;
            self.query = '';
            self.$container.on({
                'click.easyDropDown': function(){
                    if(!self.down && !self.disabled){
                        self.open();
                    } else {
                        self.close();
                    };
                },
                'mousemove.easyDropDown': function(){
                    if(self.keyboardMode){
                        self.keyboardMode = false;
                    };
                }
            });

            $('body').on('click.easyDropDown.'+self.id,function(e){
                var $target = $(e.target),
                    classNames = self.wrapperClass.split(' ').join('.');

                if(!$target.closest('.'+classNames).length && self.down){
                    self.close();
                };
            });

            self.$items.on({
                'click.easyDropDown': function(){
                    var index = $(this).index();
                    self.select(index);
                    self.$select.focus();
                },
                'mouseover.easyDropDown': function(){
                    if(!self.keyboardMode){
                        var $t = $(this);
                        $t.addClass('focus').siblings().removeClass('focus');
                        self.focusIndex = $t.index();
                    };
                },
                'mouseout.easyDropDown': function(){
                    if(!self.keyboardMode){
                        $(this).removeClass('focus');
                    };
                }
            });

            self.$select.on({
                'focus.easyDropDown': function(){
                    self.$container.addClass('focus');
                    self.inFocus = true;
                },
                'blur.easyDropDown': function(){
                    self.$container.removeClass('focus');
                    self.inFocus = false;
                },
                'keydown.easyDropDown': function(e){
                    if(self.inFocus){
                        self.keyboardMode = true;
                        var key = e.keyCode;

                        if(key == 38 || key == 40 || key == 32){
                            e.preventDefault();
                            if(key == 38){
                                self.focusIndex--
                                self.focusIndex = self.focusIndex < 0 ? self.$items.length - 1 : self.focusIndex;
                            } else if(key == 40){
                                self.focusIndex++
                                self.focusIndex = self.focusIndex > self.$items.length - 1 ? 0 : self.focusIndex;
                            };
                            if(!self.down){
                                self.open();
                            };
                            self.$items.removeClass('focus').eq(self.focusIndex).addClass('focus');
                            if(self.cutOff){
                                self.scrollToView();
                            };
                            self.query = '';
                        };
                        if(self.down){
                            if(key == 9 || key == 27){
                                self.close();
                            } else if(key == 13){
                                e.preventDefault();
                                self.select(self.focusIndex);
                                self.close();
                                return false;
                            } else if(key == 8){
                                e.preventDefault();
                                self.query = self.query.slice(0,-1);
                                self.search();
                                clearTimeout(self.resetQuery);
                                return false;
                            } else if(key != 38 && key != 40){
                                var letter = String.fromCharCode(key);
                                self.query += letter;
                                self.search();
                                clearTimeout(self.resetQuery);
                            };
                        };
                    };
                },
                'keyup.easyDropDown': function(){
                    self.resetQuery = setTimeout(function(){
                        self.query = '';
                    },1200);
                }
            });

            self.$dropDown.on('scroll.easyDropDown',function(e){
                if(self.$dropDown[0].scrollTop >= self.$dropDown[0].scrollHeight - self.maxHeight){
                    self.$container.addClass('bottom');
                } else {
                    self.$container.removeClass('bottom');
                };
            });

            if(self.$form.length){
                self.$form.on('reset.easyDropDown', function(){
                    var active = self.hasLabel ? self.label : self.options[0].title;
                    self.$active.text(active);
                });
            };
        },

        unbindHandlers: function(){
            var self = this;

            self.$container
                .add(self.$select)
                .add(self.$items)
                .add(self.$form)
                .add(self.$dropDown)
                .off('.easyDropDown');
            $('body').off('.'+self.id);
        },

        open: function(){
            var self = this,
                scrollTop = window.scrollY || document.documentElement.scrollTop,
                scrollLeft = window.scrollX || document.documentElement.scrollLeft,
                scrollOffset = self.notInViewport(scrollTop);

            self.closeAll();
            self.getMaxHeight();
            self.$select.focus();
            window.scrollTo(scrollLeft, scrollTop+scrollOffset);
            self.$container.addClass('open');
            self.$scrollWrapper.css('height',self.maxHeight+'px');
            self.down = true;
        },

        close: function(){
            var self = this;
            self.$container.removeClass('open');
            self.$scrollWrapper.css('height','0px');
            self.focusIndex = self.selected.index;
            self.query = '';
            self.down = false;
        },

        closeAll: function(){
            var self = this,
                instances = Object.getPrototypeOf(self).instances;
            for(var key in instances){
                var instance = instances[key];
                instance.close();
            };
        },

        select: function(index){
            var self = this;

            if(typeof index === 'string'){
                index = self.$select.find('option[value='+index+']').index() - 1;
            };

            var option = self.options[index],
                selectIndex = self.hasLabel ? index + 1 : index;
            self.$items.removeClass('active').eq(index).addClass('active');
            self.$active.text(option.title);
            self.$select
                .find('option')
                .removeAttr('selected')
                .eq(selectIndex)
                .prop('selected',true)
                .parent()
                .trigger('change');

            self.selected = {
                index: index,
                title: option.title
            };
            self.focusIndex = i;
            if(typeof self.onChange === 'function'){
                self.onChange.call(self.$select[0],{
                    title: option.title, 
                    value: option.value
                });
            };
        },

        search: function(){
            var self = this,
                lock = function(i){
                    self.focusIndex = i;
                    self.$items.removeClass('focus').eq(self.focusIndex).addClass('focus');
                    self.scrollToView();    
                },
                getTitle = function(i){
                    return self.options[i].title.toUpperCase();
                };

            for(i = 0; i < self.options.length; i++){
                var title = getTitle(i);
                if(title.indexOf(self.query) == 0){
                    lock(i);
                    return;
                };
            };

            for(i = 0; i < self.options.length; i++){
                var title = getTitle(i);
                if(title.indexOf(self.query) > -1){
                    lock(i);
                    break;
                };
            };
        },

        scrollToView: function(){
            var self = this;
            if(self.focusIndex >= self.cutOff){
                var $focusItem = self.$items.eq(self.focusIndex),
                    scroll = ($focusItem.outerHeight() * (self.focusIndex + 1)) - self.maxHeight;

                self.$dropDown.scrollTop(scroll);
            };
        },

        notInViewport: function(scrollTop){
            var self = this,
                range = {
                    min: scrollTop,
                    max: scrollTop + (window.innerHeight || document.documentElement.clientHeight)
                },
                menuBottom = self.$dropDown.offset().top + self.maxHeight;

            if(menuBottom >= range.min && menuBottom <= range.max){
                return 0;
            } else {
                return (menuBottom - range.max) + 5;
            };
        },

        destroy: function(){
            var self = this;
            self.unbindHandlers();
            self.$select.unwrap().siblings().remove();
            self.$select.unwrap();
            delete Object.getPrototypeOf(self).instances[self.$select[0].id];
        },

        disable: function(){
            var self = this;
            self.disabled = true;
            self.$container.addClass('disabled');
            self.$select.attr('disabled',true);
            if(!self.down)self.close();
        },

        enable: function(){
            var self = this;
            self.disabled = false;
            self.$container.removeClass('disabled');
            self.$select.attr('disabled',false);
        }
    };

    var instantiate = function(domNode, settings){
            domNode.id = !domNode.id ? 'EasyDropDown'+rand() : domNode.id;
            var instance = new EasyDropDown();
            if(!instance.instances[domNode.id]){
                instance.instances[domNode.id] = instance;
                instance.init(domNode, settings);
            };
        },
        rand = function(){
            return ('00000'+(Math.random()*16777216<<0).toString(16)).substr(-6).toUpperCase();
        };

    $.fn.easyDropDown = function(){
        var args = arguments,
            dataReturn = [],
            eachReturn;

        eachReturn = this.each(function(){
            if(args && typeof args[0] === 'string'){
                var data = EasyDropDown.prototype.instances[this.id][args[0]](args[1], args[2]);
                if(data)dataReturn.push(data);
            } else {
                instantiate(this, args[0]);
            };
        });

        if(dataReturn.length){
            return dataReturn.length > 1 ? dataReturn : dataReturn[0];
        } else {
            return eachReturn;
        };
    };

    $(function(){
        if(typeof Object.getPrototypeOf !== 'function'){
            if(typeof 'test'.__proto__ === 'object'){
                Object.getPrototypeOf = function(object){
                    return object.__proto__;
                };
            } else {
                Object.getPrototypeOf = function(object){
                    return object.constructor.prototype;
                };
            };
        };

        $('select.dropdown').each(function(){
            var json = $(this).attr('data-settings');
                settings = json ? $.parseJSON(json) : {}; 
            instantiate(this, settings);
        });
    });
})(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use @media rule.

```
@media screen and (max-width: 300px) {
    body {
        background-color: lightblue;
    }
 //add your rest of the css code for mobile

}
```

Comment: Friend where to add this code? In the home page of website in head section or where?please help!

Comment: Or can i divert traffic from mobile version to different part of same webpage?

Answer (score 0):

If your question is to set different home pages for mobile and PC version use this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  <!--
  if (screen.width <= 800) {
    window.location = "http://m.domain.com";
  }
  //-->
</script>
```